# Fingerprint GUI doesn't detect fingerprint scanner

Tags: asus, fingerprint-reader

I just got a new Asus Zenbook (UX430UA-GV456T), which includes a fingerprint scanner. It works fine for Windows, but when using Fingerprint GUI it simply doesn't detect the device. So I'm assuming I need a driver for this device, but I can't find any drivers online.

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The driver is not yet available for Linux. There is a thread in a forum where people comment on this issue https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libfprint/+bug/1641290